# How to proper setup JayData + Typescript + Local Database?

Tags: typescript, jaydata

I am starting to develop a mobile web application in Typescript and decided to use JayData. Looking online on JayData's website I only found details on how to use typescript with OData.

After much digging around I managed to get it working. I am currently facing only one issue (described later on this post).

First I would like to share the steps to get it working here in order to assist anyone trying to achieve the same.

You can follow these steps:

1. Download JaySvcUtil ([enter link description here](http://jaysvcutil.codeplex.com/))
2. Extracting the contents to a desired folder and running the following command:

   ```
   C:\temp\Jaydata\>JaySvcUtil.exe --metadataUri http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata --out northwind.js -namespace Northwind
   ```
3. This generates 2 files ('northwind.d.ts' and 'jaydata.js'). Those files can be used as a "template" for you to write your own setup classes/code.
4. Change the classes Names/Properties to reflect your own schema.
5. You are required to use both files. The .js file contains the database definitions (data types/etc).
6. After finishing the setup, add references for the Models/JayData scripts on you html page:

   ```
   <script src="scripts/libs/jaydata/jaydata.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/libs/jaydata/jaydataproviders/WebApiProvider.min.js">/script>
   <script src="scripts/models/models.js"></script>
   ```
7. On your main TS file you can initialize the DB:

   ```
   var myDB = new MyDB.Model.TodoEntities({
           name: 'local',
           databaseName: 'myDbName'
       });

       myDB.Todos.add(new MyDBModel.Todo({ TodoId: undefined, Description: '123-654-1'}));
   ```

Doing this it works like a charm. Hope it helps someone.

---

### As to my question:

Everything is working fine, except the intellisence while performing queries:

```
    myDB.Todos.filter(col => col.TodoId > 1)
                .orderByDescending(col => col.TodoId) <---NO INTELLISENCE HERE
```

On the first part of the query (filter) I have full intellisence, however on the second part (orderByDescending) **col** is not identified as of type MyDBModel.Todo. If I manually cast it to MyDBModel.Todo, it works fine.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: If you monkeyed around with the files that were generated in your step 3 in step 4, especially the d.ts file, you may have broken the intellisense there.  The files generated by JaySvcUtil should not have to be changed as they are a direct reflection of your odata datasource.  If you feel you need to change the files generated by the JaySvcUtil, you probably need to look back at the EF model and make the changes there instead.

Comment: @Jpirok The thing is that I am not using a remote datasource. I want to use typescript with a local database (WebSql). I know no other way to do it. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: I looked on jaydata.org and came across a few examples here for WebSQL.  http://jaydata.org/examples  It does not look like you'll have the option of using the jaysvcutil and will have to craft your entities by hand though. It also looks like you have the wrong provider loaded in your javascript. apparently for websql you need the SQLiteProvider.min.js...

Comment: @Jpirok I followed this instructions: [link](http://jaydata.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=171&p=1071&hilit=typescript&sid=b7fc6e4e04464bf23a1d483ea47e3de9#p719) from JayData forum. As for the SQLLiteProvider, I am not using it as it is not available in all devices as oposed to WebSql